# Is there some kind of initialization on creating c# images

Tags: c#

I noticed that the first creation of an image from an uri takes pretty long, but after one is created the others load really faster (even faster the first one).

Is there some kind of initialization on the first use of an image object? Is there a way to improve this performance?

I'm loading the images like this:

```
new BitmapImage(new Uri("directlink"));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few possibilities:

1. You may be causing extra assemblies to load the first time you try to access the image.
2. The JIT compilation could be compiling the type, causing a slight delay on the first use of this code.
3. There may be a hit the first time you try to access the URL domain, due to DNS lookup slowness.  Subsequent images may be using the DNS cache.

Comment: Thank you, and the only thing to make sure that every image load that fast is to initially create an image?

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, this is probably due to Just In Time (JIT) compilation.

As you execute your program, the CLR compiles from IL into native instructions "as it goes". This means that the first time you access any code, there is a hit as it is compiled, but once it has been done once you don't incur the penalty again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is ,
the object needs to be created, then a connection object then, the connection needs to be opened , the correct methods etc